# Bullet points not replacing - csv to xml

Tags: c#

I am reading in a CSV file and converting it to XML. The problem is, bullet points, hyphens etc.. I'm trying to replace "•" along with other characters that are not being "seen" as valid. When the XML is generated the bullet point represents as a square, in fact, anything not recognized is a square.
When I copy the "square" from the XML generated, all "special" characters are "seen" as a black diamond with a question mark inside. In the XML output it is represented as a "�".
I have tried:

```
int i = (int)'•';
Console.WriteLine(i);
```

and I see a value of 8226.

So I tried replacing `\u8226` with "html for bullet" so it will display properly, but this is not working.

I read the original CSV this way:

```
string[] csvfile = File.ReadAllLines(inputFile).Skip(1).ToArray();
```

The files I am reading will not be huge so this is why I am reading into an array.

Then I split on "," to give me the columns to convert to XML elements.
If I open the file in Excel and do the replace through Excel manually, no problems. I get the expected xml output. I would like to do this programmatically. I don't have any problems doing a replace inside the xml element with regular text, like this:

```
new XElement("elementName", columns[14].ToLower().Replace("yes", "1")
```

If I try:

```
new XElement("elementName", columns[14].ToLower().Replace("•", "htmlReplacement")
```

Nothing is changed.

Any insight would be great!

Here is the code I am using:

// regex patterns above for below replace - this works

```
        string inputFile = @"pathTo.csv";

        string[] csvfile = File.ReadAllLines(inputFile).Skip(1).ToArray();

        XNamespace xsi = XNamespace.Get("http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance");
        XNamespace xsiNsl = XNamespace.Get("something.xsd");

        XElement jobs = new XElement("Root",
            new XAttribute(XNamespace.Xmlns + "xsi", xsi.NamespaceName),
            new XAttribute(xsi + "noNamespaceSchemaLocation", xsiNsl),

            from line in csvfile
            //let columns = line.Replace(", ", "&#44; ").Replace(",0", "&#44;0").Split(',')

            let columns = Regex.Replace(Regex.Replace(Regex.Replace(Regex.Replace(line, dPat, rdPat), dPat2, rdPat2), dPat3, rdPat3), dPat4, rdPat4).Split(',')

            select new XElement("item",
                new XElement("column1", columns[0]),
                new XElement("Column2", columns[1]),
                new XElement("Column3", new XCData(columns[2].Replace("–", "-").Replace("•", "&#8226;").Replace("®", "&#174;").Replace("©", "&#169;"))),
                new XElement("Column4", new XCData(columns[3].Replace("–", "-").Replace("•", "&#8226;").Replace("®", "&#174;").Replace("©", "&#169;"))),
                new XElement("Column5", new XCData(columns[4].Replace("–", "-").Replace("\x0095", "&#8226; ").Replace("®", "&#174;").Replace("©", "&#169;").Replace("\n\n", "").Replace("\"", ""))),
                new XElement("column6", columns[5]),
                new XElement("column7", columns[6].Replace("/", "-")),
                new XElement("column8", columns[7]),
                new XElement("column 9", columns[8].Replace("$", "").Replace(" ", "").Replace(".00", "")),
                new XElement("column10", columns[9]),
                new XElement("column11", columns[10].Replace("/", "-")),
                new XElement("column12", columns[11].Replace("/", "-")),
                new XElement("column13", columns[12].ToLower().Replace("yes", "1").Replace("no", "0")),
                new XElement("column14", columns[13].ToLower().Replace("yes", "1").Replace("no", "0")),
                new XElement("column15", columns[14].ToLower().Replace("yes", "1").Replace("no", "0")),
                new XElement("column16", columns[15].ToLower().Replace("yes", "1").Replace("no", "0")),
                new XElement("column17", columns[16].ToLower().Replace("yes", "1").Replace("�", "0")),
                new XElement("column18", columns[17]),
                new XElement("column19", columns[18]),
                new XElement("column20", columns[19])));

        jobs.Save(@"outputPathFor.xml");
```

The xml created is as expected except for the unrecognized characters that are not replacing. I did try to use hex but that did not replace them either.

Thanks!

Comment: Replace should work; It isn't clear why it doesn't work for you. Can you show us a [short but complete program](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which reproduces the problem?

Comment: i think unicode use hex so transform 8226 unto hex which is \u2022

Comment: Which character set and encoding does the CSV file use? If you don't know, you have data loss caused by an incomplete specification. `File.ReadAllLines` decides on one of these Unicode encodings: UTF-8, UTF-32LE and UTF-32BE. That could be all wrong.

Comment: Hey Tom, Thanks! I think this is what the issue is.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to ensure you have a more generic way of escaping your unicode characters from the input (instead of doing `string.Replace` calls). Like the approach below:

```
public static IEnumerable<string> UnicodeXmlEscape(IEnumerable<string> input)
{
    var sb = new StringBuilder();
    foreach (var line in input)
    {
        // Loop through each character in the line to see if it
        // needs escaping.
        for (int i = 0; i < line.Length; i++)
        {
            if (char.IsSurrogatePair(line, i))
                // Escape in "&#xABC1234E" format
                sb.AppendFormat(@"&#x{0:x8}", char.ConvertToUtf32(line, i++)); // i++ to skip next one.
            else
            {
                int ci = char.ConvertToUtf32(line, i);
                if (ci > 127) 
                    // Escape in "&#xAB12" format
                    sb.AppendFormat(@"&#x{0:x4}", ci);
                else // regular ASCII
                    sb.Append(line[i]);
            }
        }
        yield return sb.ToString();
        sb.Clear();
    }
}
```

So this:

```
var escaped = UnicodeXmlEscape(new [] { 
    @"I'm trying to replace • along with other characters that are not being" 
});
foreach (var line in escaped)
    Console.WriteLine(line);
```

Will produce the output below:

```
I'm trying to replace &#x2022 along with other characters that are not being
```

Note that certain unicode characters are not legal in xml (http://www.w3.org/TR/unicode-xml/). The code above does not check for their occurrence.

**How to use this in your code**

In your code you could simply use it like this, to process each of the lines read from the input file and "xml unicode escape" them.

```
var csvfile = UnicodeXmlEscape(File.ReadLines(inputFile).Skip(1)).ToArray();
```

To get proper escaped lines, that you can use just as input to your column splitting. No more need to do any `String.Replace` later on.

Comment: @Fredou, not just that, but to use a more general approach than `String.Replace`.

Comment: oh man! that is like totally above my head! I really appreciate your response! I was hoping for something a little easier to understand. you are talking WAY above my head. It's not your answer Alex, it's my understanding of the whole thing. I was hoping there would be a simpler answer. I was hoping to be able to replace the characters while either reading the file or while creating the xml.

Comment: @user3408397, I added some more explanation at the bottom of my answer and a usage example for your specific use case.